# dynamic template not showing on click

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a dynamic component based off of an online example that I found in an article. It does not appear to be working. Here is the link to the article for reference https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d

The dynamic component is going to be a mobile navigation menu, eventually, but for now it is a simple text display just to get the concept working.

I have followed two different articles, but the article that I have shared seemed to be the most concise and simple explanation. I'm not sure what is going wrong and why it isn't generating a component for me on click.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactory, ComponentRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../../core';
import {
  Router,
} from '@angular/router';
import { ConfigAssetLoaderService } from '../../../core/services/config-asset-loader.service';
import { MobileNavbarComponent } from '../mobile-navbar/mobile-navbar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'thrive-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("mobileNavbarContainer", {read: ViewContainerRef}) container;
  componentRef: ComponentRef<MobileNavbarComponent>;

constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private configService: ConfigAssetLoaderService,
    public router: Router,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

 createComponent(side) {
    this.container.clear();
    this.mobileNavOpen = true;
    const factory: ComponentFactory<MobileNavbarComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MobileNavbarComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    this.componentRef.instance.title = side;
  }

}
```

Here is the mobile template:

```
<ng-container #mobileNavbarContainer></ng-container>
<button (click)="createComponent()">Open Nav</button>
```

Here is the mobile navigation component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimationService } from '../../../core/services/animation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'thrive-mobile-navbar',
  template: `
  <div>
    <h1>Test Text</h1>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./mobile-navbar.component.scss']
})
export class MobileNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('title') title: string;

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Comment: Where is `this.container`?

Comment: @Sergey sorry about that I have added it in

Comment: Try removing `[ngIf]`. I really can't understand the sake of `ngIf` on a template which is not shown until you do it manually. Also the problem I think is that you are using `ng-template` instead of `ng-container`.

Comment: okay let me try those two suggestions really quick

Comment: Maybe it would be enough for you to simply use `*ngIf` on a component tag instead of using dynamic component technique. It's usually used for when you don't know what there would be or it's shorter to write some resolver than many `ngSwitchCase`

Comment: That might be a fair assessment

Comment: Just in case. `*ngIf` totally deletes element from the DOM as well as destroys component when the statement is `falsy` therefore it's free to use as it won't be crowled by search engines if they are in a desktop mode. Also, if you have two menus switching (aka mobile/desktop) you can use `*ngIf="statement; else templateRef"` to show another template when statement is `falsy`. (`<ng-template #templateRef><component></component></ng-template>`)